# Inject dependencies from Application into each new PhoneApplicationPage

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, dependency-injection

My `Application` object owns object *X*. Whenever instances of `PhoneApplicationPage` are created, I want to inject a reference to *X* into them. Where can I plug in to do that?

The best way I've found so far is to use the `RootFrame.Navigated` event, but that of course executes upon each navigation, not only when the page objects are created.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:

http://funq.codeplex.com/

https://msmvps.com/blogs/vcsjones/archive/2010/11/25/a-really-super-light-and-simple-ioc-container-for-windows-phone-7.aspx

http://www.simonrhart.com/2010/03/implementing-ioc-container-in.html

Comment: There is no way to automatically inject values into a page (or any other class) constructor on WP7. Use an IOC container to get instances of whatever classes you want in your page constructors.